# How to output additional error message on password failure with Ruby

Tags: ruby, database, twitter, error-handling

I am trying to help improve this open source repository: https://github.com/michenriksen/birdwatcher/ . At the moment if the user puts in the wrong postgreSQL password, the repository outputs:

```
[-] Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "birdwatcher"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "birdwatcher"
```

Which isn't particularly useful, as it does not give the user any indication of what to do to fix the error (a gem uninistall and reinstall doesn't fix it either). In addition to the output currently generated, I would like it to output:

> Please edit the ~/.birdwatcherrc file with the correct password, or delete the file entirely, then run birdwatcher again.

Currently by looking through the repository I have isolated the following code:

```
def bootstrap_database!
  task "Preparing database...", true do
    Sequel.extension :migration, :core_extensions
    @database = Sequel.connect(configuration.get!(:database_connection_uri))
    Sequel::Migrator.run(@database, DB_MIGRATIONS_PATH)
    Sequel::Model.db = @database         
    Sequel::Model.plugin :timestamps
    bootstrap_models!           
    load_default_workspace!
  end
end
```

( https://github.com/michenriksen/birdwatcher/blob/master/lib/birdwatcher/console.rb )

Which appears to be the related section? However I cannot find anything that looks as if it would be generating the error message. Does anyone have an idea how to go about finding this, and adding the error message in? Perhaps there is default error handling in one of the called function libraries which is doing this and I could put in a call to add the additional message when the particular error is thrown?

Will it be as simple as `puts "Please edit the ~/.birdwatcherrc file with the correct password, or delete the file entirely, then run birdwatcher again."` or will I need something more advanced?

Any help much appreciated. I've never authored a Ruby gem myself, so I'm not 100% sure where and how to edit, other than it appears as though it should be a simple task once I know how. The author has obviously put a lot of effort into the repository already, so I'd like to help them make it better if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably raise when the connection is configured or the first query is run. That happens in this two lines:

```
@database = Sequel.connect(configuration.get!(:database_connection_uri))
Sequel::Migrator.run(@database, DB_MIGRATIONS_PATH)
```

Just wrap the line that raise the error with a `rescue` block:

```
begin
  # line that raise the exception
rescue Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError
  puts 'Please edit the ~/.birdwatcherrc file with the correct password, or delete the file entirely, then run birdwatcher again.'
  raise # re-raises the original method
end
```

Comment: Sweet. It works. Sorry it took a while to accept the answer. Had to work out how to build a gem locally but yep, all working fine now. Thanks!